# Parent content type Page or Page Layout?

Tags: content-type, page-layout

When to develop custom page layout via Visual Studio, which parent content type must be chosen for content type?

From different articles i see both Page and Page Layout selected as base Content type.

See:

http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2010/archive/2011/11/23/sharepoint-2010-cookbook-how-to-create-custom-page-layout-for-publishing-site-using-visual-studio-2010.aspx

and

http://borderingdotnet.blogspot.com/2012/01/creating-content-type-for-custom.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Page` (or one inherited from it like `Article page`) as the base content type for the Content Type for the content to be displayed using the Page layout

The `Page Layout` content type is to be used when you add your `Page layout` to the master page gallary, so that's for the page layout itself not the corresponding content